# Can't seem to add attestation statuss to controls inside Azsk tool in my azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops

> **Context of my environment**: I have run an custom organisation policy where i add these to my azure devops ci/cd pipeline. 
>   Next to that i added the resource group AzSKRG and with the command `Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus`  Been adding attestation statusses to some of the controls I found it not necessary to fail the pipeline. But with the last step I have some problems

I am trying to make some of the manual and verify controls to "passed" so that my developing team can run this flawless in the pipeline and i just verify the controls once every 90 days (the expiration days).
The problem i have ATM is that i can't add attestation statusses to these controlID's

Azure_APIManagement_AuthZ_Restrict_Caller_IPs
Azure_APIManagement_DP_Restrict_Critical_APIs_Access
Azure_KeyVault_AuthZ_Grant_Min_Access_policies
Azure_APIManagement_DP_Use_Secure_TLS_Version
Azure_APIManagement_DP_Dont_Reveal_Backend_Info
Azure_APIManagement_AuthZ_Enable_Requires_Approval

for the keyvault i have no clue why i can't add the attestation status. this is my output of my powershell command

```
================================================================================
AzSK Version: 3.8.0 
================================================================================
Method Name: Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus (GRS)
Input Parameters: 
Name                  Alias Value                                         
----                  ----- -----                                         
SubscriptionId        s     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx         
DoNotOpenOutputFolder dnof  True                                          
ResourceType          rt    Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults                     
ResourceGroupNames    rgns  xxxxxxxxxx                           
ControlIds            cids  Azure_KeyVault_AuthZ_Grant_Min_Access_policies
ControlsToAttest      cta   All                                           
AttestationStatus     as    NotAnIssue                                    
JustificationText     jt    Quarterly check 

You can also use: grs -s xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -dnof  -rt Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults -rgns xxxxxxxx Azure_KeyVault_AuthZ_Grant_Min_Access_policies -cta All -as NotAnIssue -jt Quarterly check  
================================================================================
Running AzSK cmdlet using security policy...
Number of resources: 1
Number of resources for which security controls will be evaluated: 1
================================================================================
Starting analysis: [FeatureName: KeyVault] [ResourceGroupName: xxxxxxxxx] [ResourceName: xxxxxxxxxx] 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking: [KeyVault]-[All Key Vault access policies must be defined with minimum required permissions to keys and secrets]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed analysis: [FeatureName: KeyVault] [ResourceGroupName: xxxxxxxxxxxx] [ResourceName: xxxxxxxx] 
================================================================================
Summary  Total Verify
-------  ----- ------
High         1      1
------  ------ ------
Total        1      1
------  ------ ------
================================================================================
** Next steps **
Look at the individual control evaluation status in the CSV file.
        a) If the control has passed, no action is necessary.
        b) If the control has failed, look at the control evaluation detail in the LOG file to understand why.
        c) If the control status says 'Verify', it means that human judgement is required to determine the final control stat
us. Look at the control evaluation output in the LOG file to make a determination.
        d) If the control status says 'Manual', it means that AzSK (currently) does not cover the control via automation OR A
zSK is not able to fetch the data. You need to manually implement/verify it.

Note: The 'Recommendation' column in the CSV file provides basic (generic) guidance that can help you fix a failed control. Y
ou can also use standard Azure product documentation. You should carefully consider the implications of making the required c
hange in the context of your application. 
Control results may not reflect attestation if you do not have permissions to read attestation data from AzSKRG
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status and detailed logs have been exported to path - C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AzSKLogs\xxxxxxxx\20181218_171945_GRS\
================================================================================
################################################################################

Starting Control Attestation workflow in bulk mode...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: 
Please use utmost discretion when attesting controls. In particular, when choosing to not fix a failing control, you are taki
ng accountability that nothing will go wrong even though security is not correctly/fully configured. 
Also, please ensure that you provide an apt justification for each attested control to capture the rationale behind your deci
sion.
Do you want to continue (Y/N): Y
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of candidate resources for the attestation: 1
================================================================================
Info: Starting attestation [1/1]- [FeatureName: KeyVault] [ResourceGroupName: xxxxxx] [ResourceName: xxxxxxxx] 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of controls that need to be attested: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ControlId            : Azure_KeyVault_AuthZ_Grant_Min_Access_policies
ControlSeverity      : High
Description          : All Key Vault access policies must be defined with minimum required permissions to keys and secrets
CurrentControlStatus : Verify

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Attestation summary for this resource:

ControlId                                      EvaluatedResult EffectiveResult AttestationChoice
---------                                      --------------- --------------- -----------------
Azure_KeyVault_AuthZ_Grant_Min_Access_policies          Verify          Passed NotAnIssue       



Committing the attestation details for this resource...
Commit succeeded.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed attestation: [FeatureName: KeyVault] [ResourceGroupName: xxxxxxx] [ResourceName: xxxxxx]
```

```

As for the api management controlID's , I've looked inside my powershell module folder inside
`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzSK\3.8.0\Framework\Configurations\SVT\Services`
And searched for the control ID's in the apimanagement.json
But couldn't find it in the json files, Maybe inside the powershell module these control's  are not present and inside the azsk pipeline task they are .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgrade to the latest version and run the scan command again. This should solve your issue.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question; it is better suited as a comment.

Comment: This was indeed the answer , totally forgot about the fact that this answer was still unanswered on Stack

Comment: Which software exactly had to be upgraded to the latest version? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: The [Secure DevOps Kit for Azure (AzSK)](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit) needs to be updated to the latest version.